# How can I change the bounds to a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, collision-detection, starling-framework

I'm using starling and I exported the png sequence of a movieclip,  with the width of 762 and a height of 992. But the actual width and height of the movieclip is (184, 134)... it's just the animation that gives it that high width and height of  (762, 992)... how can I change the bounds of this movieclip to (184,134)... because it is throwing off my collision detection... I'm not familiar with getbounds() as far as today, but I've tried bounds.setTo () and by trying to change bounds.width/and height... please any help and insight is much appreciated

Comment: Weird export dimensions. Probably try re-exporting, or adjust PNGs to be 184x134.

Comment: Yes it is, It's the animation that causes this,  I have the character and the board meeting at one point of the stage from two points from outside the stage... right now no simple way of of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a mask. Add this movie clip inside another, add new layer, add a rectangle with desired dimensions, and make it mask. Then try and export it again ...